# How to display the data in template

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am new to Angular2.

sample.html

```
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">


<button (click)="sendData(yourName)">send data</button>
<p>{{receivedData}}</p>

sample.ts

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
selector: 'hello-world',
templateUrl: 'src/hello_world.html'
})
export class HelloWorld {
yourName: string = '';
receviedData : string = "";
console.log(receivedData);
sendData(yourName) : void{
console.log("sent",yourName);
receivedData = yourName;
```

}

}

I am trying to send the data as a input to the sendata function, then assign it to the receivedData variable and then display receivedData variable in template using interpolation.

```
 I appreciate any help related to this.

 Thanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You need to make a change in your component ts file. You are using following:

```
receivedData = yourName;
```

However, you need to use following:

```
this.receivedData = yourName;
```

first one try to assign value to a local variable, but answer assign the value to global variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. If I may suggest, try to use IDE like VS Code. This would help specially because angular learning curve is steep.